# Can you set a variable to console.ReadLIne()?

Tags: c#, variables, variable-assignment, console.readline

I am new to programming here. This is a question that i have been mulling over. Can you set a variable to Console.ReadLine() in c# and then call the variable instead of typing Console.ReadLine() everytime? For example:

```
//Set Variable
var read = Console.ReadLine();
//Call vaariable
read;
```

Comment: what do you mean by calling variable ? you *use* a variable like `Console.WriteLine(read);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
//Set Variable
Func<string> read = Console.ReadLine;
//Call vaariable
read();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a delegate, like this:

```
var readOp = new Func<string>(() => Console.ReadLine());
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(readOp());
```

or this, or whatever else:

```
string myLine = readOp();
```